# "Need to disable some ESLint rules" error while make the build of next js app

Tags: next.js, eslint

I want to deploy my `Next.js` file on the server. When I hit the command `npm run build` it shows the error

> Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules

I am unable to find the mistake because the app is working properly in localhost but when I want to make the build it shows an error. the packages in my `package.json` file is

```json
{
  "name": "yourguide-next-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.2",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.2.0",
    "cjs": "^0.0.11",
    "cookies": "^0.8.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "next": "12.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tinymce": "^6.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^12.2.5",
    "eslint": "8.20.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.3"
  }
}
```

I don't know the `ESLint rules`. kindly give me the solution of this problem.

Comment: _"when I want to make the build it shows an error"_ - And what error is that?

Answer (score 21):

To ignore eslint during build in nextjs, you have to add this line to the next.config.js file:

```json
eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore eslint by editing your *next.config.js* file.

**Example:**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
    eslint: {
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
/* ...Your other config rules */
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This will ignores eslint, if you want to keep the eslint rules try running the build command locally and fix the errors that pop up.

Comment: Worked will, thanks for detailed code

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to share the exact error you are getting when making the build.

To disable some rules for eslint all you need to do is edit your .eslintrc.json file to make it look like below or you can add comments like https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/no-abusive-eslint-disable.md

```
{   "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true   },   "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"   ],   "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",   "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"   },   "plugins": [
    "react"   ],   "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/function-component-definition": [
      2,
      {
        "namedComponents": "arrow-function",
        "unnamedComponents": "arrow-function"
      }
    ],
    "no-use-before-define": [
      "error",
      {
        "functions": false,
        "classes": false,
        "variables": false
      }
    ],
    "react/no-unknown-property": 0,
    "no-console": 0,
    "no-plusplus": 0,   } }
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error too I fixed it by just removing the eslint dependency from my `package.json`